# Save file path in CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp, path

CakePHP doesn't save the file path I provide. The record has 3 columns (id, path, description), but the 'path' column is empty every time I try to add a path.

```
$this->UpdateFile->saveAll($this->request->data)
```

The files are dynamically generated, so they have a structure like this:

```
data[UpdateFile][n][path]
data[UpdateFile][n][description]
```

How can I save the path?

Comment: What would the expected result look like and what is the current actual result?

Comment: In the database: Scheme: id | path | description, Data: 01 | /some/dir/file.ext | some description, but Cake saves 01 | | some descroption

Comment: try removing app/tmp/cache/models/cake_model_default_your_model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the input field is set to 'disabled="disabled"' Browsers won't transmit the values. I've removed this attribute and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->request->data['UpdateFile']['path'] = $this->request->data['UpdateFile']['n']['path'];
$this->UpdateFile->saveAll($this->request->data);
```

Comment: CakePHP **does** save all the data correctly, but the path (it's always empty). I think the problem is that PDO filters too much...

Comment: if `data[UpdateFile][n][path]` actually has a value in it, then your format that the save array expects is wrong. That's why I moved the filename back a level in the requuest data array. If the value is empty when doing `pr(data[UpdateFile][n][path]);` then the code you posted above is not relevant and we will need the component code instead.

Comment: I've logged the form data and path isn't in the Post-Array, just description and type

Comment: Then check the name of your image upload input field. to pass it along with `this->request->data` the name should start with `data[UpdateFile]`. Something like `<input type="file" name="data[UpdateFile][file]" />`

Comment: I've var_dumped the whole data-Array, there was only "description" and "type", nothing else, but I've found the solution (see solution marked post). Thanks for your help!